# Targeting an element outside of its parent container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a section with an anchor tag. Is it possible to target another element on the page outside of that anchor tag's parent?

For example, when a user hovers over the anchor tag in the following code, the paragraph tag inside of another container gets targeted, whether it's changing the font size, color, whatever, etc. Any suggestions or guidance would be much appreciated!

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">hover me</a><li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="target-container">
  <p id="target-element">Target Element</p>
</div>
```

Seems like there has to be a way to do this with js, as css won't work obviously since the target element is outside of the container.

Comment: Just use `document.getElementById("target-element")` to target that element.

Comment: Welp, that definitely did the trick. Thanks man

Comment: *Is it possible to target another element on the page outside of that anchor tags parent?* Of course! That's the whole point of the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer and comments, this can also be achieved with just CSS.

**NOTE**: The `:has` CSS Pseudo-class does not work in Firefox for Android.

```css
/* Select the element with the class of target-container that is the next sibling
   to an anchor that is being hovered over that is a descendant of a 
   div with a class of container. */
div.container:has(a:hover) ~ .target-container p {
  color:red;
  font-size:2em;
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">hover me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="target-container">
  <p id="target-element">Target Element</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to select elements include `document.querySelector` and `document.getElementById`.

In this case, you can add event listeners for `"mouseenter"` and `"mouseleave"` on the anchor element, and change or revert the styles of the other element in those event handlers, respectively.

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.container a');
const target = document.getElementById('target-element');

// example for changing the color of the target
a.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  target.style.color = 'dodgerblue'; // set new color on hover
});
a.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  target.style.color = ''; // reset after
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">hover me</a><li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="target-container">
  <p id="target-element">Target Element</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can select elements by a lot more than the two you've mentioned. You can also use `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I didn't say you can only select elements this way. I just mentioned that you *can* use these two methods.

Comment: Your answer seems to sound like you are saying that these are the two ways to select and that these are the two ways to have mouse events.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I see what you mean. I've changed the wording.

Answer (score 0):

With modern CSS yes You can do this with [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and a [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). Check browser [`has()` support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility) to see if it meets your needs.

```css
.container:has(a:hover) ~ .target-container #target-element {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">hover me</a><li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="target-container">
  <p id="target-element">Target Element</p>
</div>
```